# Computing ext over graded rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, homological-algebra, graded-modules

This question came up as I was reading Beilinson, Ginzburg, Soergel paper [*Koszul Duality Patterns in Representation Theory*](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1996-9-02/S0894-0347-96-00192-0/).

> Suppose that $A$ is a Koszul ring (for the definition of Koszul ring see page 2 of BGS) and let $N$ be a graded $A$-module. As I understand it should be true that $$ \operatorname{ext}_A ^{i+1} (A_0, N) = \hom_A (K^i,N)$$ where $ K^i = \ker(P^i \rightarrow P^{i-1})$.

However I haven't been able to show it. The way I have been trying to show it is by induction since in the case were $ i = 0$ maybe its possible to use the fact that $ ext^1 _A (A_0, N) = \hom_A (K^0, N)/ Im(i^*)$ where $ K^0 = \ker ( P^0 \rightarrow A_0)$ and $ i: K^0 \hookrightarrow P^0$. But in order to even start here I have to show that $ Im(i^*)$ is zero and I haven't been able to convince myself that it is.

Comment: I believe your question come from understanding proof of (3)$\Rightarrow$(1) of Prop 2.1.3, which actually require more than $N$ just to be graded module, it also require $N$ to be pure.  Have you tried using that condition as well?

Comment: @Aaron, ack! I have an older version of the paper and they don't state that N is pure. It seems in the version on the AMS website this is corrected. I think it should work now, thanks! :)

Comment: @Anette Please consider self-answering your question, so that it gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).